# Adding a hit counter to Desktop Intelligence/Xi 3/Business Objects webpage?

Tags: counter, business-objects, hit, hitcounter

for my company I am making a report in Xi3/Desktop Intelligence that pulls data via free hand SQL and makes a html file displaying the data, updating every 20mins. We want to incorporate a hit counter that will show us the number of times this report is being viewed.

I found a couple basic templates online. I tried copying and pasting them into a cell, but the output HTML page just displayed the full HTML (unrendered by my browser). I am decent at writing my own HTML, but I just do not understand how to stick my own HTML code in a dynamically updating report in Xi3.

Moreover, I doubt (for legality reasons) my company will be okay with me using a free hit counter template I find online, especially considering they all seem to reference a third party website to do the actual "counting." Any ideas of the best way to implement/learn how to create a visitor counter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** include HTML in a DeskI report.  In the cell that contains the HTML, click Format Cell; on the "Number" tab, there is a checkbox for "Read as HTML".  Make sure that's checked off.  Note that you won't see the rendered HTML within DeskI, but it will display when viewed in Infoview.